# Как получить все поля, кроме одного, используя scenarios в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при получении данных из формы мы писали в базу все полученные данные, кроме одного.
Например, у нас есть в форме 3 поля: f1, f2, f3.
Мы в модели можем написать так:

```
public function scenarios()
    {
        return [
            'my' => ['f1', 'f2'],
        ];
    }
```

Все отлично, но если у нас полей не 3, а 30, то переписывать все доступные поля не хочется.
Есть ли способ через сценарии написать, чтобы доступными были все, кроме одного, ну, или кроме нескольких?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если необходимо именно через сценарии, то можно вспомнить что это обычная функция, вы в ней можете получить все поля модели, удалить то поле которое не нужно и передать в сценарий

```
public function scenarios()
{
    $fields = $this->attributes();
    unset($fields['somefield']);

    return [
        'my' => $fields,
    ];
}
```

Можно другим путем пойти, очистить поле перед валидацией:

```
public function beforeValidate(){
    $this->somefield = null;
    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

А можно и просто в контроллере не передавать модели то поле которое не надо:

```
public function actionSomeAction(){
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $post['somefield'] = null;

    $model = new Model();

    if($model->load($post)){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Ну и еще разные пути)